# Why vue-cli understand I've installed vue-cli-plugin-vuetify and vuetify-loader?

Tags: vuetify.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3, vue-cli-4, vuetify-loader

When I create a fresh `vue-cli` project via this command

`vue create hello-word`

and this command to install `vuetify`

`vue add vuetify`

Then I saw my git changes like this

[image]

Two new dependencies have been installed in `package.json`.

1. `vue-cli-plugin-vuetify`
2. `vuetify-loader`

At first glance, I thought `vue.config.js` has specified using these two, but it's content only have these code.

```js
module.exports = {
  "transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ]
}
```

So, how does `vue-cli` know I've installed this new vuetify loader?

Does it automatically pick those up?

Comment: did you find any solution? i have the same issue, and coudnt use vuetify

Answer (score 1):

After running `vue add vuetify` choose Vuetify 3 if you are using Vue 3:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

vuetify-loader is a treeshaking plugin for Webpack. It gets installed automatically when you install Vuetify using "vue add vuetify".

So, vuetify-loader is used by Webpack for treeshaking the Vuetify components to only include the ones that you imported in your app. This way Webpack should be able to lower your build size by importing only the required components, and not all the Vuetify components.

See [Vuetify Treeshaking](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/)

And this is the [vuetify-loader project on Github](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader)